# AWS Athena filtering array with multiple dictionaries with on most recent dates

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have the following json structure that I'm querying with Athena. How can I with filter the most recent dictionary?

```
AA": {

        "BB": {
            "CC": [
                {
                    "lastUpdateDate": "2020-10-18",
                },
                {
                    "lastUpdateDate": "2021-10-18",
                }

            ]
           }
        }
```

I try to use UNNEST but I it doesn't work so far.

Comment: Can you share the UNNEST code that you have used ?

Comment: Please show your current code (SQL query) and desired output.